# rsync not copying my files

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

I was trying to use rsync to only copy the .c files from a given directory. Therefore I tried this command:

```
rsync -nrv --include="*.c" --exclude="*" test/ temp/
```

The output:

```
sending incremental file list
test1.c
test2.c

sent 63 bytes  received 18 bytes  162.00 bytes/sec
```

The data I wanted to be copied was found, but when I check 'temp', it is empty.
I also tried to let rsync create the directory and the output is the following:

```
sending incremental file list
created directory temp
./
test1.c
test2.c

sent 66 bytes  received 21 bytes  174.00 bytes/sec
```

But when I check for the directory 'temp', it doesn't exist. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you gave `-n`, which means "dry run"!

remove the `-n`

you should at least check man page for the options you used, to understand the meanings:

```
 -n, --dry-run               perform a trial run with no changes made
```